# [Pascal]Why the 'or' operator is not working?

Tags: pascal

why the following Pascal code doesn't display the message skipping the forbidden symbols?
P.S. It works if I remove the "or (a[i]<>'$')" part. How should I change the code so it would work?

```
  var
  a : string;
  i,b : integer;
begin
  i:=1;
a:='abc!d$';

  for i:=1 to ord(a[0]) do begin
  if (a[i]<>'!') or (a[i]<>'$') then
       write(a[i])
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both `!` and `$` are forbidden, the test should be an `and`, not an `or`.

And instead of using `ord(a[0])` to get the length of the string, you should use the provided `length(a)` function. You don't need to know that the first byte of the string hold its length, just trust your language library.